# Django named routes like Laravel

Tags: python, django

I'm starting to learn about Django Framework. I have this urls in my `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^hello/$','article.views.hello'),
)
```

My questions are: 
**Can I give this routes a name, like i would in Laravel?
 How can i reference those named routes from template?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
url(r'^hello/$','article.views.hello', name="hello"),
```

You would reference it in a template as:

```
{% url 'hello' %}
```

For more information, including how to give arguments to a named URL, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns).